JSCodeShift not working as expected, white space not preserved
I'm trying to turn
<ZText>Test {a} test</ZText>

into
<ZText><Trans>Test {a} test</Trans></ZText>

My jscodeshift script does this:
  const wrapWithTrans = (children) => {
    return [
      j.jsxElement(
        j.jsxOpeningElement(j.jsxIdentifier('Trans'), []),
        j.jsxClosingElement(j.jsxIdentifier('Trans')),
        children
      ),
    ];
  };

path.node.children = wrapWithTrans(path.node.children);


The output is
<ZText><Trans>Test{a}test</Trans></ZText>

Any idea what I can do to preserve the white space?
